# Protocol adoption by extension causing "Abort trap: 6" on Xcode 8.3.2/Swift 3.1

Tags: swift, xcode

The following code causes the Swift compiler to crash with `Command failed due to signal: Abort trap 6`:

```
import UIKit

protocol ZeroProtocol {
    static var zero: Self { get }
}

// CGPoint already has CGPoint.zero so we attempt to adopt ZeroProtocol.
// This causes "Abort trap: 6" on compilation.
extension CGPoint: ZeroProtocol {}
```

I'm almost certain that this code compiled a few months ago without trouble. Strangely, adopting the protocol with my own struct doesn't produce any error:

```
import UIKit

protocol ZeroProtocol {
    static var zero: Self { get }
}

struct TestStruct {
    static var zero = TestStruct()
}

// Works fine.
extension TestStruct: ZeroProtocol {}
```

I have submitted a bug report to Apple, but any **workaround** would be appreciated.

Comment: Worth noting that it does compile in the latest Swift 4 snapshot – so looks like the bug has already been fixed.

Comment: As a workaround, you could override the property in your module by adding `static var zero: CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) }` to the extension definition.